# is there a way to auto adjust widths in ng-grid?

Tags: ng-grid

I'm having trouble with widths of my columns.  I don't know what width they will be beforehand, nor do I want to specify each column's width.  Is there an attribute that I can use that auto adjusts all the column widths based on the content (including the column header)?

Answer (score 12):

Woot!  I came up with a pretty cool answer!  Setting the width to `"auto"` was really not working for me.  Maybe it is because I'm using an `ng-view`?  Not sure.  So I created 2 new functions you can put in your `controller.js`.  Using them like this will give you computed column widths!  Read the code comments; there are some caveats.

### Example usage, controllers.js:

```
var colDefs = makeColDefs(rows[0]);
colDefs = autoColWidth(colDefs, rows[0]);

$scope.phones = rows;
$scope.gridOptions = {
    data : 'phones',
    showFilter : true,
    enableColumnResize : true,
    columnDefs : colDefs
};
```

### The code, controllers.js:

```
/**
 * Create a colDefs array for use with ng-grid "gridOptions". Pass in an object
 * which is a single row of your data!
 */
function makeColDefs(row) {
    var colDefs = [];
    for ( var colName in row) {
        colDefs.push({
            'field' : colName
        });
    }
    return colDefs;
}

/**
 * Return a colDefs array for use with ng-grid "gridOptions". Work around for
 * "auto" width not working in ng-grid. colDefs array will have percentage
 * widths added. Pass in an object which is a single row of your data! This
 * function does not do typeface width! Use a fixed width font. Pass in an
 * existing colDefs array and widths will be added!
 */
function autoColWidth(colDefs, row) {
    var totalChars = 0;
    for ( var colName in row) {
        // Convert numbers to strings here so length will work.
        totalChars += (new String(row[colName])).length;
    }
    colDefs.forEach(function(colDef) {
        var numChars = (new String(row[colDef.field])).length;
        colDef.width = (numChars / totalChars * 100) + "%";
    });
    return colDefs;
}
```

### Jasmine test, controllerSpec.js:

```
'use strict';

var ROW = {
    'col1' : 'a',
    'col2' : 2,
    'col3' : 'cat'
};
var COLUMN_DEF = [ {
    field : 'col1'
}, {
    field : 'col2'
}, {
    field : 'col3'
} ];
var COLUMN_DEF2 = [ {
    field : 'col1',
    width : '20%'
}, {
    field : 'col2',
    width : '20%'
}, {
    field : 'col3',
    width : '60%'
} ];

/* jasmine specs for controllers go here */

describe('controllers', function() {
    beforeEach(module('myApp.controllers'));

    it('should make an ng-grid columnDef array from a row of data.',
            function() {
                expect(makeColDefs(ROW)).toEqual(COLUMN_DEF);
            });

    it('should return an ng-grid columnDef array with widths!', function() {
        var colDefs = makeColDefs(ROW);
        expect(autoColWidth(colDefs, ROW)).toEqual(COLUMN_DEF2);
    });

});
```

Comment: Be warned that above solution makes ui-grid 3.0 (ng-grid) terribly slow and sluggish.

Comment: I wonder why?  I did report an issue a while back for ng-grid being slow.

Answer (score 0):

Use ui-grid, is must better: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/204_column_resizing

but https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/wiki/Configuration-Options

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
                init: function (gridCtrl, gridScope) {
                    gridScope.$on('ngGridEventData', function () {
                        $timeout(function () {
                            angular.forEach(gridScope.columns, function (col) {
                                gridCtrl.resizeOnData(col);
                            });
                        });
                    });
                },
                data: 'scopeDataField',
                columnDefs: [
                    {
                        field: 'property1',
                        displayName: 'property1title',
                        width: '100px' // a random fixed size, doesn't work without this
                    },
                    {
                        field: 'property2',
                        displayName: 'property2title',
                        width: '100px'
                    }

                ],
                enableColumnResize : true
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

See answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/32605748/1688306

Column width calculated by column name or datum, whichever is longer.

Answer (score -1):

Yes!  In your `columndefs` you can set the width to `auto` and this will automatically size the columns based on the width of the data and/or header.

Reference: [Defining Columns](https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/wiki/Defining-columns)

Comment: This did not work.  Here is a quote from the link you provide: _note: "auto" only works in single page apps currently because the re-size happens on "document.ready". Still working on improving that."_

Comment: Here's whats quirky about this. If I display all columns, it works. If I display 1 column, it only works when my grid is in a scrollable panel and it exceeds the limit. If it's under the limit and there is no scroll (minimal rows), then nothing shows up! If I put a fixed length, then it works no problem.. but becomes a huge burden if I resize my window :(

Comment: This `auto` width setting works quite horribly even in latest ui-grid. It destroys so much data.

Answer (score -1):

I am using ui-grid. The following code is working for me. You can try this.

```
First you need to add a module dependency 'ui.grid.autoResize' in your main module.

Then add css class something like this 

.grid {
  width    : 400px !important;
  max-width : 400px !important;
  height   : 600px !important;
}
```

And finally add the ui-grid directive in your html file like this. Keep in mind don't forgot to add the '`ui-grid-auto-resize`' in your grid directive.

```
<div id="grid1" ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid" ui-grid-auto-resize></div>
```

Comment: This controls the grid itselfs auto-resize, the OP is asking about column auto-resize