# AngularJS UI-Grid: dynamical column width calculation

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using AngularJS [UI-Grid](http://ui-grid.info/) (latest version) to display datasets with different columns count and column names and data itself (CSV files uploaded by users), and I can't make columns to render with proper width - typically that files have more than 20-30 columns, and columns appears too narrow. I can make fixed width for all columns, but I want width depends from data.

Adding ui-grid-auto-resize directive don't gives much.

With `width: "*"` only 15 columns are rendered, and horizontal scroll is disappears

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22161396/ng-grid-auto-sizing-columns-width/32605748#32605748

Answer (score 0):

Try using `width: "*"` in your columnDefs

Comment: With width: "*" only 15 columns are rendered, and horizontal scroll is disappears

Comment: Try making a Plunker for your actual code.  That may help others troubleshoot it.