# ng-grid column not displayed in grid

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

i am using ng-grid 2.0.11 with angularjs 1.2.16

I am facing one strange issue while display data in grid.

When i am trying to load data some of the column getting displyed in grid. Once i resize

browser then it triggers event and shows all the columns defined in the column definition.

Some of the column displayed means data binding is not the issue.

But yes i have cell templates and row tempalte defined.

How i can resolve this issue ?

-Thanks,

Yogesh

Comment: Does it work if you use the default cell and row templates? Are you setting the size of the columns somewhere that could be causing this? Can you create a plunker to demonstrate?

Comment: yes i have tried by removing cell as well as row template having the same issue. i am setting width of the column as "width : 185 " in col definition if i remove this then column will appear as per col-definition but very close to each other if i resize browser then they getting full size.. now how to set width ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try setting the width to auto, or see this link for another option:
[is there a way to auto adjust widths in ng-grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17174096/is-there-a-way-to-auto-adjust-widths-in-ng-grid)

Or perhaps minWidth and maxWidth would work for you:
https://github.com/angular-ui/ng-grid/wiki/Defining-columns

Comment: Yes its worked. I have added both the "width: 'auto', minWidth: 60" in col definition and its started working in all browser.                                            Thanks